# How do i convert List into datetime.date object?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, datetime

I'm trying to extract data from my db and display it in a well formatted form.

When db gives me the date i'm trying to display it in the form of String 'Day/Mon/Year'. I have used the following code to do so , but it is throwing me the error.

How do i convert a list to date.time object ?

```
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime
db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=news")
if db:
  print("DB CONNECTED")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select day from (select date(time) as day, count(id) as errors from log where status != '200 OK' group by day order by errors desc limit 1) as seq")
t = c.fetchall()
res = datetime.strftime(t,'%b %d, %Y')
print(res)
db.close()


TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'list'
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that t is not what you expect it to be. It's likely a list of row results. which means that if you change  ```res = datetime.strftime(t,'%b %d, %Y')``` to ```res = datetime.strftime(t[0],'%b %d, %Y')``` this code might work. Try printing t and see what it is, if you provide that in the question it'll be easier to help.

Comment: Yea I have tried that too .
It is showing the same Typeerror
descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'tuple'

Comment: Okay, so you're getting a list of tuples from the query, most likely its a row list combined with row results. Without you printing the variable t and showing us the result this will be a crapshoot, you should edit your questing with the output of ```print(t)```. That being said ```datetime.strftime(t[0][0],'%b %d, %Y')``` might work, but if you dont share what ```print(t)``` outputs it's hard to help you here!

Comment: But normally you would not use `strftime` like this; it's a method you call on a class instance, so (once you get the right object for `t`) you would do `t.strftime('%b %d, %Y")`.

Comment: Yea it worked , thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you need to iterate over the list. maybe this wil work, havent tested it, but thats the way i do it.

```
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime
db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=news")
if db:
  print("DB CONNECTED")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select day from (select date(time) as day, count(id) as errors from log where status != '200 OK' group by day order by errors desc limit 1) as seq")
t = c.fetchall()
c.close()
db.close()
for dates in t:
    print(datetime.strftime(dates, '%b %d, %Y'))
```